# Rewrite URL - redirect everything BUT images

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, url

HI,

I have a working redirection that looks like this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)weihnachtsshop/(.*)$ /hochzeitsshop [R=301,L]
```

everything like www.shop.com/weihnachtsshop/product.html get's redirceted to www.shop.com/hochzeitsshop.

My problem now is, that i need this redirection to *exclude* all images, like www.shop.com/weihnachtsshop/product.jpg - these links should not get rewritten.

What's the best way to approach this?

PAT

Comment: I'd be interested in the solution to this too.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` redirects only file that does not exist. It could be enough in your case no ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)weihnachtsshop/(.*)$ /hochzeitsshop [L,R=301]
```

Comment: and bmp or tiff, webp ? :p (just kidding)